# How do I create a servlet module as asset for a platform setup?

Tags: hiconic

I want to bundle a TF markdown asset with a TF servlet asset into a single platform setup.

In principle I understand that I need to use an "aggregator". Or do I need a "setup" asset for this purpose?

So basically:

```
platform-aggregator
|
+--- markdown-aggregator
|
+--- servlet-setup (?)
```

or

```
platform-setup-asset 
|
+--- markdown-aggregator
|
+--- servlet module (?)
```

And why? Or are there multiple ways to achieve this?

My final goal is to run:

```
jinni  setup-local-tomcat-platform  --installationPath here --setupDependency group:platform-setup#1.0
```

to get a working tomcat setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following structure to assemble your setup:

```
your-setup
|
+--- markdown-aggregator
|
+--- servlet-module
|
+--- tribefire.setup.classic:web-platform-setup#3.0
```

A `setup` asset is an aggregator that brings various dependencies including one that aggregates a platform defining asset and normally ends with a suffix `-setup`.

In the given example the dependency that transitively introduces the platform is the `tribefire.setup.classic:web-platform-setup#3.0`

So your dependency tree covers now 3 aspects:

1. include your documentation related dependency
2. include your module that deploys a servlet
3. include a platform that will host the other aspects

The 3. aspect makes your aggregator a setup and implies that you also suffix your aggregator with `-setup`.